# Create new instance with changed attribute for property

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to create an instance like that

```
public class TableDynamicParameters
{
    [Parameter]
    [ValidateSet("Table1", "Table2")]
    public string[] Tables { get; set; }
}
```

but I want to change/set the attribute `ValidateSet`.

I tried to accomplished this with the `TypeDescriptor`, but I have clearly not so many experience with reflection.

```
    var tableDynamicParameters = new TableDynamicParameters();
    var typeDescriptionProvider = TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(tableDynamicParameters, new ValidateSetAttribute("Table1_New", "Table2_New"));
    var tableDynamicParameters_new = (TableDynamicParameters)typeDescriptionProvider.CreateInstance(new ServiceContainer(), tableDynamicParameters.GetType(), null, null);
```

Background for the question:
I want to write a PSCmdlet to search in SQLite Tables, the parameter "Tables" should include in ValidateSet all existing tables.

Comment: That's simply a bad approach. Most attribute code doesn't use TypeDescriptor in the first place, and this isn't the intended usage of it. If you need to change the values of an attribute, then you're probably using the wrong API in the first place. Does the tool expose a secondary, non-attribute-based, API to do the same thing?

Comment: I used a different approach for a dynamic ValidateSet, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823910/pscmdlet-dynamic-auto-complete-a-parameter-like-get-process